# esbuild error when starting Node Vite app in Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, vite

I'm getting an error related to esbuild when trying to start my app - I've seen others post the same question, but I've tried everything in the answers, and it's still failing.

```
error when starting dev server:
Error: 
You installed esbuild for another platform than the one you're currently using.
This won't work because esbuild is written with native code and needs to
install a platform-specific binary executable.

etc....
```

I've tried adding `supportedArchitectures` to `.yarnrc.yml`, I've added `node_modules` to my `.dockerignore` and `yarn install` to the Dockerfile, so I'm confused as to why it's still not installing the right version. Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:20

COPY . /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y libssl-dev \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN yarn install && \
  yarn cache clean && \
  yarn run build

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["yarn", "run", "dev"]
```

This is my `vite.config.ts`:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import viteTsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths';
import eslint from 'vite-plugin-eslint';
import path from 'path';

export default defineConfig({
  base: '/',
  esbuild: {
    target: 'esnext'
  },
  plugins: [react(), viteTsconfigPaths(), eslint()],
  server: {
    watch: {
      usePolling: true
    },
    open: false,
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    strictPort: true,
    port: 3000,
    fs: {
      strict: false,
      allow: ['..']
    }
  },
  publicDir: 'public',
  build: {
    sourcemap: false,
    outDir: 'build',
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        main: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build/index.html')
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Update: I was able to get it to build by adding this to package.json:

```
  "resolutions": {
    "rollup": "npm:@rollup/wasm-node@*",
    "esbuild": "npm:esbuild-wasm"
  },
```

I'm getting a 404 now at http://localhost:3000.

```
Everything was working fine with CRA but I needed to migrate to Vite because of dependency issues, and the fact that CRA is no longer being updated.
```